# How to disable button until email validated in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    email: ''
  },
  computed: {
    isEmailValid() {
      return '/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/'.test(this.email)
    },
    isDisabled: function() {
      return !this.email || this.isEmailValid;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>
    <input class="input-mobile-email" type="text" placeholder="Your email" id="email" v-model="email" name="email" />
  </p>
  <button :disabled='isDisabled'>Send Form</button>
</div>
```

I am trying to disable the button until the email address is validated. So for that I have taken a computed property and written a function. And then I am trying to pass the function's name to `isDisabled`.

But there is an issue with the validation and the button doesn't get enabled, even if a correct email address is entered.

This is a jsfiddle where I tried the functionality https://jsfiddle.net/k69cr0sf/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems with your code

1. A regex must not be enclosed in quotes `''`
2. Your `isDisabled()` function returns the wrong value, because it returns `true` if `this.isEmailValid == true` which is obviously wrong.

You can also simplify your logic, as your regex won't match an empty string. Thus your `isDisabled()` can simply return the negated result of the regex test, ie `return !/.../.test(this.email)`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    email: ''
  },
  computed: {
    isDisabled: function() {
      return !/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(this.email)

    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>
    <input class="input-mobile-email" type="text" placeholder="Your email" id="email" v-model="email" name="email" />
  </p>
  <button :disabled='isDisabled'>Send Form</button>
</div>
```

PS: You can add external scripts also to your code snippets, if you click on *Add External scripts*  and input the url. Thus for simple cases, there is typically no need to link to external jsfiddles and you can keep your questions self-contained.